# UIPanGestureRecognizer is working for only uiview not for uiimageview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Can anyone give me the exact reason why the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in not working for `UIImageView` and working for `UIView` I didnt find any blog. Below is my code(working now)

```
UIView *endImage=[[UIView alloc]init];

    endImage.backgroundColor=[[UIColor yellowColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3f];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panOnEndImage = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanOnLine:)];

    panOnEndImage.delegate=self;
    [endImage addGestureRecognizer:panOnEndImage];
    [anotherUIView addSubview:endImage];
    [panOnEndImage release];
```

if i am changing endimage as a `UIIMageView` object then that panning is not working...Thanks in advance your suggestion is more important.

Comment: Please add this line and try.

[endImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this line and try. `[endImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];` so this is the answer.(right ;)!